# Something like MySQL triggers but as a whole?

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER `after_customer_insert`
AFTER INSERT ON `customer`
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    UPDATE `user`
    SET
        `customers_count` = `customers_count` + 1
    WHERE `id` = NEW.`user_id`;
END$$
```

Instead of calling `UPDATE user` for each new row in `customer`, would be possible to have a trigger as a "whole"? I mean something like

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER `after_customer_insert`
AFTER INSERT ON `customer`
BEGIN
    UPDATE `user`
    SET
        `customers_count` = (
            SELECT COUNT(`id`)
            FROM `customer`
            WHERE `user_id` = `id`
        )
END$$
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Triggers are mainly intended to be used to execute actions related to a change on a *single* row, usually changing another single row, as Jake points out. Of course you can implement logic that (redundantly) carries out the same action on largely the same result set for each row updated, but the question is, why would you not issue a single `UPDATE` statement subsequent to your original `UPDATE`? You may have a good reason for this, hence Jake's question about the overall situation.

e.g. (syntax *not* tested, but the general idea holds)

```
UPDATE u set u.customer_count = x.newcount
from
user u inner join 
(
select user, count(*) as newcount
from user group by customer_id
) x
```

Comment: then you can simply wrap both updates in a parameterised procedure.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it will work since I did it myself once. I would order a few things on a table everytime a new insert would happen BUT it's not good practice in my point of view. There is probably a possible improvement in your code which will save you this trouble.

Also, even if this trigger will deal with all rows on the table, it will be called EVERY time an INSERT happens...

Could you please provide an overall situation description, maybe I could help you finding a better solution... :-)

Comment: The situation is so simple: update the number of customers owned by a given user :)

Comment: Well, it is simple, BUT, once again, not good practice. You are storing unnecessary data. It could improve performance considering you don't need to count anything on retrieval, but you need to update it on each insert so... I'm not sure it's worth it, actually I'm sure it's not and you should implement a "count" on your code or query and maybe you don't even need this count all the time...

Comment: I'm sure you retrieve some information from these tables very often and not ALWAYS you need to know this count, so this performance issue you are creating with the trigger might not be good depending on your load etc...

Answer (score 0):

The only case, when such type of trigger may be required, is for query:

```
INSERT INTO customer SELECT * FROM customer_old;
```

But for this case you can disable triggers before query, do insert-update and enable triggers back.

I highly doubt, that you often inserts multiple customers at a time. Or even if it is true, you trying to do premature optimisation.